# use notifyListeners even if there aren't changes

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, listener, flutter-provider

I have a particular problem.

I'm using Provider to manage the profile image (among other parameters) of the logged user.
The image is actually an URL that points to an image stored on firebase storage.

The problem is that if the image pointed by the url changes, even calling   `notifyListeners()` the widget that uses the URL doesn't rebuild because the URL string is actually hasn't changed.
How can I "force to rebuild" a widget using   `notifyListeners()` iven if there aren't changes apparently?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your string value with class that contain id field and change it every time when image has been updated

```
class Vault {
    final String id;
    final String url;
    const Vault(this.id, this.url)
}
```